# nested json data with parent

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
<?php
    include "../dcon.php";
    $sql = "select * FROM posts left join comments on comments.Cpostid=posts.PostId left join likes on likes.postid=posts.PostId";


        $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);  
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        $menus=array();


     for($i=0; $i<$result; $i++){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_all($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
     foreach($row as $index => $row ){
        $menus[]=[
        'PostId'=>$row['PostId'],
        'PostVideo'=>$row['PostVideo'],
        'PostDesc'=>$row['PostDesc'],
        'PostImage'=>$row['PostImage'],
        'PostedBy'=>$row['PostedBy'],
        'UserName'=>$row['UserName'],
        'Status'=>$row['Status'],
        'PostParent'=>$row['PostParent'],
        'likes'=>$row['likes'],
        'comments'=>[
        $index => [
        'commentsid'=>$row['commentsId'],
        'comments'=>$row['comments'],
        'Cpostid'=>$row['Cpostid'],
        'time'=>$row['time'],
        ],],
        
        'likes'=>[
        $index =>[
        'Likeid'=>$row['Lid'],
        'dislikes'=>$row['dislikes'],
        'postid'=>$row['postid'],
        'userid'=>$row['userid'],
]]
];
        }
     }  
     echo json_encode($menus,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

**
this is my code i have three table posts table, comments table, and likes table. i have a left joined all three tables with postid common in all three tables. im getting all data  perfectly but im getting repeating data of postdata (ex:Postid=1) i dont want that.
my problem is  getting repeating data of Postdata(ex:Postid=1) i want to make a parent of Postdata where postsdata=1 and i want to insert all data into parent
**

```
[
        {
            "PostId": "1",
            "PostVideo": "v2.mp4",
            "PostDesc": "this is a tutorial on bench press",
            "PostImage": "null",
            "PostedBy": "Irfan khan",
            "UserName": "irfan",
            "Status": "1",
            "PostParent": null,
            "likes": {
                "Likeid": "1",
                "dislikes": "0",
                "postid": "1",
                "userid": "1"
            },
            "comments": {
                "commentsid": "1",
                "comments": "awesome video",
                "Cpostid": "1",
                "time": "2020-12-16 17:33:33"
            }
        },
        {
            "PostId": "1",
            "PostVideo": "v2.mp4",
            "PostDesc": "this is a tutorial on bench press",
            "PostImage": "null",
            "PostedBy": "Irfan khan",
            "UserName": "khan",
            "Status": "1",
            "PostParent": null,
            "likes": {
                "Likeid": "1",
                "dislikes": "0",
                "postid": "1",
                "userid": "1"
            },
            "comments": {
                "commentsid": "2",
                "comments": "good workouts",
                "Cpostid": "1",
                "time": "2020-12-16 17:33:33"
            }
        },
        {
            "PostId": "1",
            "PostVideo": "v1.mp4",
            "PostDesc": "Chicken generally includes low fat in the meat itself (castrated roosters excluded). The fat is highly concentrated on the skin. A 100g serving of baked chicken breast contains 4 grams of fat and 31 grams of protein, compared to 10 grams of fat and 27 grams of protein for the same portion of broiled, lean skirt steak.",
            "PostImage": "im1",
            "PostedBy": "Rehmat",
            "UserName": null,
            "Status": "1",
            "PostParent": null,
            "likes": {
                "Likeid": "20",
                "dislikes": "0",
                "postid": "1",
                "userid": "4"
            },
            "comments": {
                "commentsid": null,
                "comments": null,
                "Cpostid": null,
                "time": null
            }
        },
        {
            "PostId": "1",
            "PostVideo": "v1.mp4",
            "PostDesc": "Chicken generally includes low fat in the meat itself (castrated roosters excluded). The fat is highly concentrated on the skin. A 100g serving of baked chicken breast contains 4 grams of fat and 31 grams of protein, compared to 10 grams of fat and 27 grams of protein for the same portion of broiled, lean skirt steak.",
            "PostImage": "im1",
            "PostedBy": "Rehmat",
            "UserName": null,
            "Status": "1",
            "PostParent": null,
            "likes": {
                "Likeid": "26",
                "dislikes": "0",
                "postid": "1",
                "userid": "4"
            },
            "comments": {
                "commentsid": null,
                "comments": null,
                "Cpostid": null,
                "time": null
            }
        },
        {
            "PostId": "3",
            "PostVideo": null,
            "PostDesc": "this is an image of chicken",
            "PostImage": "post.jpg",
            "PostedBy": "khan",
            "UserName": null,
            "Status": "0",
            "PostParent": null,
            "likes": {
                "Likeid": null,
                "dislikes": null,
                "postid": null,
                "userid": null
            },
            "comments": {
                "commentsid": null,
                "comments": null,
                "Cpostid": null,
                "time": null
            }
        },
        {
            "PostId": "9",
            "PostVideo": null,
            "PostDesc": "gdhgh",
            "PostImage": "ghghdf",
            "PostedBy": null,
            "UserName": null,
            "Status": null,
            "PostParent": null,
            "likes": {
                "Likeid": null,
                "dislikes": null,
                "postid": null,
                "userid": null
            },
            "comments": {
                "commentsid": null,
                "comments": null,
                "Cpostid": null,
                "time": null
            }
        }
    ];
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what you are trying to to here?  What output are you trying to get?  What "error" are you referring to?

Comment: This would seem to be a problem with whatever is generating the data, not something to be handled with post-processing. Maybe your SQL query is wrong, for example?